# Multivariate Pade approximant

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, approximation

Does Mathematica generate multivariate or just two-variate [Pade approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant)? If so, what is the generating command?

Comment: Similar question was asked in this forum some time ago, but I don't find it (maybe, was deleted by the author). No. multivariate Pade approximant is not implemented in Mathematica at the present. See the results of its  [Google search](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=multivariate+pade+approximation&ei=odCEYfPDBtaK9u8P09q9iAo&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwizmLnDzYD0AhVWhf0HHVNtD6E4ChDx0wN6BAgBED4&biw=1280&bih=884&dpr=1).

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to implement it in specific cases. Set the multivariate polynomial of the desired degree. Make a list of equations equating the $n$ derivatives (from zero). Then `Solve` for the coefficients. Can you provide an example of the expression that needs approximation and the desired degree?

Comment: As an alternative, for a 2 dim case, you could try first to make a Pade approximation along the x direction and with the result another one along the y direction.

Comment: @DanielHuber: Compare `PadeApproximant[
  PadeApproximant[Exp[x*y], {x, 1, 2}], {y, 1, 2}] /. {x -> 2.3, 
  y -> 2}` which results in `72.3389` with `Exp[2.3*2]==99.4843`.

Comment: @rhermans: Whereas the Taylor polynomial of degree `n` approximates a function up to `n^-c` with some `c>0`, its Pade approximation does it up tp `Exp[-c*n]` with `c>0`. Hope you feel the difference.

Comment: @user64494 I don't understand what you mean, sorry.